# Build fails after not enough RAM even after swap

Tags: android, ram, swap

I have a 4GB RAM and I have to work in android environment. Some components in the source needs high RAM as a result, I made a swap file of 8GB and I have a 4GB RAM. My RAM is 11mb or less while compiling and the swap file is merely at 1GB out of 8GB. How can I use more swap space? I have only a terminal running while in the environment.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I switched from source building to Prebuilt chromium and it fixed. Track the Prebuilt changes from Omni gerrit by typing: 'Prebuilt chromium cm'. This error is related to low memory (RAM). The one who has 8GB+ RAM, he/she don't need Prebuilt chromium :-)